# What is the concentration of silver in tap or freshwater in the United kingdom

Tags: ocean, geochemistry

Can anyone tell me the concentration of silver in uncontaminated water ways, or treated tap water in the united kingdom? sources would be desirable too

Comment: I would recommend a friendly letter to https://www.bgs.ac.uk/ - They might have a dataset. Otherwise try to ask local water management companies. It would help the question if you could include what you want to do with the data.

Comment: They do, see: http://www.bgs.ac.uk/gbase/geochemicalMaps.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Monitoring results from UK groundwaters 1996-2007, Silver:

Sites 2929

Samples 19420

Min <0.04 µg/l

Max 79.6 µg/l

Average 0.457 µg/l

[Source - Defra](http://dwi.defra.gov.uk/research/completed-research/reports/DWI70_2_215_Monitoring_Data.pdf)

> Routine monitoring for trace elements in drinking water is only
>   conducted for the elements specified in the Water Supply (Water
>   Quality) Regulations. Specified elements include antimony, arsenic,
>   boron, cadmium, chloride, chromium, copper, fluoride, iron, lead,
>   manganese, mercury, nickel, selenium and sodium. Monitoring for other
>   elements will only normally be conducted in response to specific
>   identified risk. Recently DWI has funded investigations of uranium1
>   and molybdenum2 in drinking water in response to recent developments
>   in WHO guideline values. Both these studies showed a good level of
>   compliance should the WHO guideline value be adopted as a standard.

Also...

> Water companies also conduct raw water monitoring and these results
>   are reported to Drinking Water Inspectorate. Preliminary analysis suggests most of the 
>   raw water monitoring relates to elements already covered by the
>   regulations but a few companies monitor for additional elements in raw
>   water. A summary of the additional elements and (number of companies
>   monitoring). Silver (4).

[Source - Defra 2](http://randd.defra.gov.uk/Default.aspx?Menu=Menu&Module=More&Location=None&Completed=0&ProjectID=17665)

> Average silver concentrations in natural waters are 0.2-0.3 µg/litre.
>   Silver levels in drinking-water in the USA that had not been treated
>   with silver for disinfection purposes varied between "non-detectable"
>   and 5 µg/litre. In a survey of Canadian tapwater, only 0.1% of the
>   samples contained more than 1-5 µg of silver per litre. Water treated
>   with silver may have levels of 50 µg/litre or higher; most of the
>   silver will be present as nondissociated silver chloride.

[Source - WHO](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/silver.pdf)

Comment: The minimum and maximum are probably an effect of lithologies that the water was in contact with. Would be interesting to see those measurements on a map. The average could be somewhat misleading depending on the area of interest. The question should still outline this.

Comment: The BGS did have a program of geochemical mapping. The basic atlas information and purchase links for the maps are here: http://www.bgs.ac.uk/gbase/geochemicalMaps.html The element sampling included silver (Ag).